# How do I make Lua pause from running a while?

Tags: function, lua

I was looking for a way to pause my program to allow the user to read before it closes but the function (os.sleep(timeSeconds)) doesn't exist apparently. Anyone know a workaround?

Comment: See: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SleepFunction

Comment: @BartKiers, I need to research more, sorry! But LeleDumbo answered it.

Comment: No problem. I posted a link to the Wiki because it contains more examples besides the one LeleDumbo already mentioned. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of `os.clock()` and `os.time()`. Ex:

```
function sleep(n)
  local t = os.clock()
  while os.clock() - t <= n do
    -- nothing
  end
end
```

n is in seconds. Feel free to make the `os.time()` version.

Answer (score 2):

Better use OS built-in facilities to retain output window instead of introducing artificial delays. What if user runs your program from already opened command window or redirects output to file? You're forcing him to waste time for nothing.